# How to track two different collisions in SpriteKit Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have seen many methods on the internet, but I'm still very confused on how this is done. Ive legitimately have spent 3 hours yesterday on trying to acomplish this, but anyway the question I have is I have 3 main SKSpriteNodes in my game: man, ground, and arrow. Im trying to make it so that when the man jumps he is only able to jump once until returning back to the ground. My plan is to have it so that when the jump button is pressed a condition is changed and won't be changed back till the man hits the ground again. Im also trying to make it so that when an arrow contacts him it will be a game over and run a line of code. This is the code I have so far

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  arrow jump
//
//  Created by Joy Cafiero on 3/29/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 3rd Dimension Studios inc. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit

var timer = NSTimer()
var condition = 1
var arrow = SKSpriteNode()
var man = SKSpriteNode()
var bg = SKSpriteNode()
var ground = SKSpriteNode()
var buttonRight = SKSpriteNode()
var buttonLeft = SKSpriteNode()
var buttonJump = SKSpriteNode()
let moveGrounRight = SKAction.moveByX(200, y: 0, duration: 1)
let repeatMoveGroundRight = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveGrounRight)
let moveGrounLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-200, y: 0, duration: 1)
let repeatMoveGroundLeft = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveGrounLeft)
let runningMan1 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man1.png"))
let runningMan2 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man2.png"))
let runningMan3 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man3.png"))
let runningMan4 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man4.png"))
let runningMan5 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man5.png"))
let runningMan6 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man6.png"))
let nuetralMan = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man nuetral.png"))
let jumpingMan1 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "jumping man1"))
let jumpingMan2 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "jumping man2"))
let jumpingMan3 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "jumping man3"))

let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([ runningMan1, runningMan2,                 runningMan3,  runningMan4,  runningMan5,  runningMan6], timePerFrame: 0.15)
let jumpingAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([jumpingMan1, jumpingMan2,     jumpingMan3], timePerFrame: 0.1)
let nuetralAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([nuetralMan],     timePerFrame: 0.05)
let repeatAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation)

let manGroup:UInt32 = 1
let groundGroup:UInt32 = 2
let arrowGroup:UInt32 = 0x1 << 3


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5)

    man = SKSpriteNode(texture: nuetralMan)
    man.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),     CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    man.size = CGSize(width: man.size.width * 2, height: man.size.height * 2)
    man.zPosition = 15
    man.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: man.size)
    man.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    man.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    man.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = manGroup
    man.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = groundGroup

    self.addChild(man)

    let bgTexture = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "wild west landscape.png"))

    bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
    bg.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    bg.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 100)
    bg.zPosition = -1
    self.addChild(bg)

    let groundtexture = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "sandy ground.png"))

    ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundtexture)
    ground.size = CGSize(width: CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), height: ground.size.height)
    ground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 0)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, ground.size.height-255))
    ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    ground.zPosition = 20
    ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundGroup
    ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = manGroup


    self.addChild(ground)

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(7, target: self, selector: Selector("timerUpdate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    buttonRight.color = SKColor.redColor()
    buttonRight.position = CGPointMake(200, 200)
    buttonRight.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    buttonRight.zPosition = 25

    self.addChild(buttonRight)

    buttonLeft.color = SKColor.redColor()
    buttonLeft.position = CGPointMake(100, 200)
    buttonLeft.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    buttonLeft.zPosition = 25

    self.addChild(buttonLeft)

    buttonJump.color = SKColor.greenColor()
    buttonJump.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 200, 200)
    buttonJump.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    buttonJump.zPosition = 25

    self.addChild(buttonJump)


}

func timerUpdate() {
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    var timeIncrease:NSTimeInterval = 0
    var randomArrow = [self.frame.height / 20 + CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 65, self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 65, self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 65, self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 65]
    timeIncrease = timeIncrease + 7
    let arrowTexture = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "arrow.png"))
    let movingArrow = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.width/100)-5+timeIncrease)
    let removeArrows = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let repeatmoveArrows = SKAction.sequence([movingArrow, removeArrows])
    arrow = SKSpriteNode(texture: arrowTexture)
    arrow.size = CGSize(width: arrow.size.width, height: arrow.size.height)
    arrow.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), randomArrow[random])
    arrow.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(arrowTexture.size().width - 100, arrow.size.height / 2))
    arrow.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    arrow.zPosition = 10
    arrow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = arrowGroup
    arrow.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = manGroup
    arrow.runAction(repeatmoveArrows)
    arrow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = arrowGroup
    arrow.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = manGroup

    self.addChild(arrow)

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if buttonRight.containsPoint(location) {
            man.xScale = 1
            man.runAction(repeatMoveGroundRight, withKey: "MoveRight")
            man.runAction(repeatAnimation, withKey: "Run")
        }

        if buttonLeft.containsPoint(location) {
            man.xScale = -1
            man.runAction(repeatMoveGroundLeft, withKey: "MoveLeft")
            man.runAction(repeatAnimation, withKey: "Run")
        }

        if buttonJump.containsPoint(location) {
            if(condition == 1) {
            man.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            man.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 400))
            man.runAction(jumpingAnimation)
            }
        }


}
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if buttonRight.containsPoint(location) {
            man.removeActionForKey("MoveRight")
            man.removeActionForKey("Run")
            man.texture = nuetralMan
        }
        if buttonLeft.containsPoint(location) {
            man.removeActionForKey("MoveLeft")
            man.removeActionForKey("Run")
            man.texture = nuetralMan
        }

    }
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if buttonRight.containsPoint(location) {
            man.removeActionForKey("MoveRight")
            man.removeActionForKey("Run")
            man.texture = nuetralMan
        }
        if buttonLeft.containsPoint(location) {
            man.removeActionForKey("MoveLeft")
            man.removeActionForKey("Run")
            man.texture = nuetralMan
        }

    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        condition = 1
        man.texture = nuetralMan
        print("contact")
    }



func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? You've said you will add arrows later so I guess the only collision/contact detection you need at the moment is between the man and the ground? You'll need to set up your collisionBitMask so that the man cannot go through the ground and your contactTestBitMask so you get notified when the man has touched the ground so you can re-enable your 'jump' action.

Comment: Is your didBeginContact getting called at all?

Comment: Yes my didBeginContact function is in there and as far as I know I have inserted the categoryBitMasks and contactTestBitMasks are there.